# Are Qt stored queries for SQLite faster?

Tags: database, qt, sqlite

I am using SQLite and reading over the [docs for QSqlQuery class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html).

There are several binding examples for previously stored queries, such as this:

```
     QSqlQuery query;
     query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
                   "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
     query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
     query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
     query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
     query.exec();
```

Is this primarily a programming convenience or is there actual performance benefit for frequently used queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the performance but rather the security. With this statement you tell the database what are variables and what is your query. This makes SQL Injection imposible. If you write the SQL yourselve you need to assure that any variable input is properly escaped.